# How to diff only one line across different branches?

Tags: git, line, diff

This command will compare everything:

```bash
git diff current_branch other_branch -- file.java
```

BUT I would like to compare **only one line**, for only one file across different branches, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the -L option with git diff command to specify the line number you want to compare. Here's the command to compare a specific line in a file across different branches:

`git diff current_branch other_branch -L <filename>:<line-number>:<line-text> -- <filename>`

Replace `<file-name>` with the name of the file you want to compare, `<line-number>` with the line number you want to compare, and `<line-text>` with the content of the line you want to compare. For example:

`git diff current_branch other_branch -L MyFile.java:10:"System.out.println('Hello')" -- MyFile.java`

This command will compare line 10 of MyFile.java with the content System.out.println('Hello') between current_branch and other_branch.

Comment: Not working for me, throws error: "fatal: bad revision"

Comment: The "fatal: bad revision" error occurs when Git cannot recognize the provided revision or branch name in the repository's history. Make sure you have the correct branch names. You can list all the branches in your repository by running 'git branch --all'